# Is it necessary to set public ip on ec2 instance behind internet facing ELB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

Is it necessary to set public ip on ec2 instance behind ELB which is internet facing in AWS?

I saw many examples of instance in public subnet and the instance is enabled a public ip but I wonder why it's required if there is internet facing alb in front of a instance.

I think if there is internet facing ALB, it would be fine if I disable a public ip on ec2 instance in public subnet because a client get reach to alb and alb can route the request to a instance which have only private ip address.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. In fact the EC2 instance can even be on a private subnet and not a public subnet, as long as you allow traffic from the ALB's public subnet through the instance's security groups.